# open source shiny server on an instance on gcp can't connect to cloud sql

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, shiny-server

I am trying to host a shiny app on the open source shiny server which is installed on a virtual machine on gcp. The app is trying to connect to a remote Postgresql database that's also on gcp's cloud sql.

Below is my code for database connection

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="test",
                 host="**.**.**.**",
                 user="username",
                 password="pwd", port=5432)
```

I had white listed the public ip address of my gcp's instance on cloud sql. But still my app doesn't run.
The app runs fine on R studio server(which is also installed on the same instance). Can someone please help or provide any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: the logs didn't give any error message

Answer (score 2):

My app work's now. It seems I made a naive mistake.

For future users, below is what I did wrong and how I corrected it.

While creating the app on R studio server, I installed all my packages from R studio server. And I didn't thought that these packages are not installed at the root, they were installed at the user level and shiny-server can't access these.
I installed all the required packages again at the root

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('packagename', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

and then my shiny-app works.